# Why google cloud monitoring cannot be used for data reporting?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-monitoring

I am exploring cloud monitoring and unable to understand, how to show my dataset as a report on cloud monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

You have some data which you need to create reports. Is that right?

So I guess you try to create some dashboard.

When you see data in Loggging you can create "log based metrics" which you can use in a dashboard under Monitoring.

Comment: my data is in big query dataset that I want to display in cloud monitoring but I can't do that, this is what  I am not able to understand, like what is the difference in cloud monitoring and data studio, both are creating dashboards from dataset right??

Answer (score 0):

`Cloud monitoring` is more used for infra metrics on your resources (memory usage, CPU…) and log based metrics.

All these metrics can be displayed in a monitoring dashboard.

If you want to display a data from datasets and tables, `Datastudio` is more adapted.

I have this concern too on my side, I have a failures tables for `Dataflow` jobs and `Airflow` orchestration errors and I display them in a `Datastudio` dashboard.

I can display errors for a range dates  (partition on creation date).